# Replacing drip pipe in raised bed

Tags: watering, raised-beds, drip-system

I have a half inch drip pipe in my raised bed that I use to connect emitters to for watering my vegetables. The pipe has worn off and I need to replace it. The attached picture shows the connection. Any idea how I can remove the pipe and connect a new pipe so there are no leaks?
[image: raised bed drip pipe connection]

Comment: Is the problem now a leak here? Or is the black pipe bad elsewhere? You may have to dig down towards the source, cut that pipe and put a fitting on.

Comment: The black pipe has a leak somewhere else